# After change URL do something

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using javascript to load my desired path and i want to do some codes after changing the url. here is my simple code.

```
$(".addfr").click(function(){
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;

    if ((pathname == "/index.php") || (pathname == "/")) {
        $( "#tabbtn3" ).trigger( "click" );
        $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".sideBaricons").offset().top
        }, 600);
    }
    else{
        window.location.href = '/index.php';
        $( "#tabbtn3" ).trigger( "click" );
        $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".sideBaricons").offset().top
        }, 600);
    }

});
```

When i clicked `.addfr` when I'm not in `index.php` I redirect to `index.php` and I want to focus on specific element after that. But what happens is that my code redirects and focuses on my previous page not after the page loads.

advance thanks for the help.

Comment: how are you supposed to execute part of your script in another page?

Comment: Umm.. I smell some design flaw here.. You should consider analysing your design. Once you have redirected the browser to some other page, what's the point in writing your scripts in current page?

Comment: ... and duplicating code...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can pass a parameters after the redirect and within the index.php page on document ready setup the focus

take a look on my code

```
$(function() {
    var url= window.location.href;
    if (url.indexOf('setFocus=true') > 0) {
        $("#tabbtn3").trigger("click");
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(".sideBaricons").offset().top
        }, 600);
    }
});
$(".addfr").click(function() {
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
    if ((pathname == "/index.php") || (pathname == "/")) {
        $("#tabbtn3").trigger("click");
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(".sideBaricons").offset().top
        }, 600);
    } else {
        window.location.href = '/index.php?setFocus=true';
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for this code. i already tried this. but the code doesnt execute when it redirects to index.php?setFocus=true

Comment: var url= window.location.href; i fixed an issue , the url should be  window.location.href; also this functions should be within index.php

Comment: this code saved me. thanks for this. to everyone, thanks for letting me know that every time it loads a page i flushes the previous script.

Answer (score 2):

If you change `window.location.href` you are given a fresh browser context (it's like hitting refresh).  No code can execute after this change.  Your options for making this work are mostly limited to adding your desired code to the page you are redirecting your user to or working with something rather complex called the [History API](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html)

Comment: This should be the answer. History API is the way to go. +1

Answer (score 0):

Setting the URL to a new page throws away all running code.

One option: You can load the other page's content into the current page, e.g. using an Ajax call, if you want your code to remain present (and not just change the browser URL).

*note: Something seems awfully wrong with the design though to require this. Best you state the overall aim of your pages :)*